# Multiple web sites in one Azure Web App

Tags: azure, web

Is it possible to host 2 different sites in one Web App? I copied contents of both sites to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\web1` and `D:\home\site\wwwroot\web2` folders and bounded 2 subdomains `web1.domain.com` and `web2.domain.com` to my Azure Web App. I saw recommendation to edit `ServiceDefinition.csdef`, but I can't find it. I guess because it was not deployed with VS.

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: ServiceDefinition.csdef is for Azure Cloud Services, not Web Apps, so you can disregard that.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to host 2 different sites. 
It can be done by creating virtual directory.

1. Publish the root project with help of VS.
2. On Azure portal from the web app create a virtual directory through app settings.
3. Now again publish the child project but edit the destination url like:
    "http://123.azurewebsites.net/Child"

Answer (score 0):

You're using Azure Webapp so there are no *.csdef files anymore. You can do this in the Azure Portal. Click on Application Settings blade and scroll down to "Virtual Applications and directories".

Here you can create additional apps. For example, here is one with 3 virtual apps. Note the path to the physical files.

Finally, when you deploy in your CI/CD pipeline, you'll have specific the name of your virtual app.

[image]